# How to pass variable to stride by argument

Tags: swift

I'm trying to pass an Int constant to my for loop's stride by argument. It takes type T.stride.

```
let notchStep:Int = 5

    for degrees:Double in stride(from: 0, to: 359, by: notchStep) {
```

I get this error:

Cannot invoke 'stride' with an argument list of type '(from: Int, to: Int, by: Int)'. What type of value can I pass to by or how can I cast my Int to an appropriate type?

Comment: Try removing `:Double`

Comment: That does now work. I just had to cast degrees when it's used later. Can you explain why? Why doesn't swift do automatic widening or narrowing?

Comment: This is another good example forf the nonsense of type annotations. Unlike Objective-C Swift's strong type system does not support mixed types. Delete **both** annotations, then the compiler infers that all types are `Int`. If you need `Double`  write `let notchStep = 5.0` and `stride(from: 0.0, to: 359.0, by: notchStep`. Very easy. Basically never annotate types unless the compiler complains about it.

Comment: So basically you just use casting where you need it instead of setting the types of variables?

Comment: *So basically you just use casting where* the compiler *needs it*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `:Double` in your code, so it reads:

```
let notchStep: Int = 5

for degrees in stride(from: 0, to: 359, by: notchStep) {
    // do something
}
```

Looking at the method signature, I think mixing `Ints` and `Doubles` is generating the issue.